# Select item in listbox to go to that url?

Tags: c#

when I click on a item in my listbox I need to go to that URL. 
But I am getting the error `Cannot conver System.Uri to string`

Here is my code:

```
private void lbFavo_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbFavo.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                string link = lbFavo.SelectedText;
                webBrowser.Navigate(lbFavo.SelectedItem);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to give full url of the site with http or https, for example

```
//Fine
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.lk");
```

//Error

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.lk");
```

So make sure you pass the qualified url to the Navigate() method. Also you can't directly use SelectedItems property use the following code,

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: Read again the question, the error is `Cannot conver System.Uri to string` so the user is passing a Uri to the Navigate function.